# Spaces in the table adapted to the textwidth

Tags: tabularx

Is it possible to compute the minimal width necessary for the column (it does tabularx) and divide the remaining space (for instance to \textwidth) into the spaces between columns equally? Thanks a lot

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{table}
    \label{table:table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\centering}X>{\centering}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \toprule
    \textbf{1}     & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}    \\ \midrule
    A     &    BBBBB  &   AAAAAAAAAAAA\\ 
    B            &   b   &   b     \\ 
    C      &     c     &    c   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

After advice:

How to add space before the first column and behind the last column, please?

How to make an exception and do no space between two or the columns?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}



\begin{center}  
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc@{}}
\hline
A & B & v\\
C & D & b\\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understand your question you want `tabular*` that adds space between columns rather than changing column width

Comment: Yes. The widths of columns are automatically determined, and then I would like to divide the rest of textwidth between the column spaces.

Comment: see https://www.learnlatex.org/en/more-08#specifying-the-total-table-width

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: How to add space before the first column and behind the last column, please?

Comment: `@{}` explicitly removes space but you could add `@{\hspace{1cm}}` or perhaps simpler make the specified width be .75\textwidth and centre it so you get space either side. Please don't add solutions to the question, you can post them as a answer.